# How can I delete a specific element of a list in a combined list of lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am trying to find a way to check a list which contains several other lists for a specific element and delete it.

So basically I have 2 lists (a and b) which are combined in another list (c)

```
a= ["aa","bb"]
b= ["aa","dd"]
c=[a,b]
```

Now I am trying to delete all elements named "aa"

```
c.remove("aa")
```

Sadly this doesn't work and I get the error "*ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list*" because "aa" is not literally mentioned in c.

In the end I also want to print out all the lists in c and what they contain. Something like that:

```
c= a: bb, b: dd
```

- Is there a way to delete elements in several lists with a single command like I tried with combining them in another list c?
- And how can I print out the list c in the end similar to how I described it above?

Comment: For each sublist `L` you want to create `f(L)` where `f` is "remove all `aa` elements". Then you create a list of returned f-s of sublists: `res = [f(a), f(b)]`. This is what map for: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map .

Comment: `filter` might be helpful if you make a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
a = ['aa', 'bb']
b = ['aa', 'dd']
c = [a, b]

c = [[x for x in sublist if x != 'aa'] for sublist in c]
```

This solution will remove *all* `'aa'` elements, while `list.remove('aa')` in a regular `for` loop will only remove the *first* occurrence in each sublist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is probably the easiest way :)

Comment: But can you maybe explain to me in a bit more detail how the last line of your code works?

Comment: @NewHere, For each outer list comprehension, i.e. `for sublist in c`, the inner list comprehension, `[x for x in ...]`, constructs a list. The result is a list of lists.

Comment: Thank you for the explenation :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to iterate through the individual `list`s in `list` `c`. For example

```
>>> a = ["aa", "bb"]
>>> b = ["aa", "dd"]
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> for i in c:
...   i.remove("aa")
... 
>>> c
[['bb'], ['dd']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output looks like a dictionary. You can create this using a dict comprehension, as such:

```
a= ["aa","bb"]
b= ["aa","dd"]
mylist_names = ['a','b']
c={name:[x for x in vals if x!='aa'] for name, vals in zip(mylist_names, [a,b])}

>>> c
{'a': ['bb'], 'b': ['dd']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using numpy

```
import numpy as np

a= ["aa","bb",'cc']
b= ["aa","dd", 'kk']
c= np.asarray([a,b])

to_remove = ['aa']

c = [x[~np.isin(x,to_remove)].tolist() for x in c]
```

output = [['bb', 'cc'], ['dd', 'kk']]

Should work for everything you need including multiple items you want to get rid of.

```
import numpy as np

a= ["aa","bb",'cc']
b= ["aa","dd", 'kk']
c= np.asarray([a,b])

to_remove = ['aa', 'kk']

c = [x[~np.isin(x,to_remove)].tolist() for x in c]
```

output = [['bb', 'cc'], ['dd']]